# CryptoApi: Export a certificate without the private key?

Tags: c, security, winapi, rsa, cryptoapi

I have generated a self signed certificate using the `CertCreateSelfSignCertificate` function. This yields a PCCERT_CONTEXT.

How can I export the certificate stored in the PCCERT_CONTEXT variable with only the public key? I want to do this, to send it to other parties in the network, so these are able to encrypt messages using the public key.

I thought this was a straight forward option, but it isnt.

Answer (score 3):

No need for a pfx.

The certificate is present inside the structure **CERT_CONTEXT** : just save the content of the buffer pointed by the member **pbCertEncoded** and whose length is the value of the member **cbCertEncoded**.

Moreover, the public key from this certificate is directly present in the **CERT_CONTEXT** structure : **pCertInfo->SubjectPublicKeyInfo**. For example, you can import it using **CryptImportPublicKeyInfo** and then call **CryptEncrypt** to encrypt data.

With these two options, you have all what is needed to start encrypting messages. Of course, the private key must be kept safe to be able to decrypt encrypted data.

Comment: Can I also use CryptSignAndEncryptMessage and pass the public key info as recipient argument? I think I need to somehow convert the public key info to a CERT_CONTEXT ?

Comment: @Erik: Mounir has right. *Private* key are saved separately. If you just save the `cbCertEncoded` bytes starting from `pbCertEncoded` in the file which you get extension .cer then other will be able to use your certificate, but they will get no access to your private key which are saved in the key container.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you will need to first [put](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376009%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) the certificate into a certificate store and then export it using [PFXExportCertStoreEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa387313%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) passing dwFlags of 0 (i.e. not setting EXPORT_PRIVATE_KEYS).

P.S. nothing is ever straight forward when dealing with cryptography libraries, be it CryptAPI, JSSE, OpenSSL... it's always a nightmare.

Comment: Thanks. The function will probably do what I want, in a way. Still, exporting a whole store as pfx, when I only want to export a single certificate with the corresponding public key doesn't look clean and good. There must another way to go.

Comment: well, the idea is that you will definitely be saving this certificate in some store anyways -- otherwise you will loose the private key.  So once it is in a store, you can export the certificate from it.  You don't need to export the whole store to pfx.